# can't pass values to MvxCommand from the hosting Activity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, icommand

I am trying to pass two values to MvxCommand as shown int he code below. The first value is of type string and the latter is Enum.
But I get the following error:

```
    the non-generic type MvxCommand can’t be used with type arguments
```

Please let me know how to fix this error.

**code**:

```
        //in View „Activity"
    ViewModel. DexCommand.Execute(result, value);

        //in ViewModel 
public IMvxCommand DexCommand => new MvxCommand<string, VRTEnum>((res, val) =>
    {

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

> the non-generic type MvxCommand can’t be used with type arguments

Here is the source code snippet :

```
namespace MvvmCross.Commands
   {
      public interface IMvxCommand : ICommand
        {
          void RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
          void Execute();
          bool CanExecute();
        }

      public interface IMvxCommand<T> : ICommand
        {
          [Obsolete("Use the strongly typed version of Execute instead", true)]
          new void Execute(object parameter);
          [Obsolete("Use the strongly typed version of CanExecute instead", true)]
          new bool CanExecute(object parameter);

          void RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

          void Execute(T parameter);

          bool CanExecute(T parameter);
        }
    }
```

you can see that the `IMvxCommand<T>` parameter is a `T`

so if you want to pass two parameters , i think you could use a `Tuple` to turn them into a single object.

e.g

```
 new MvxCommand<Tuple<string, VRTEnum>>(Action);
```